# Node & Express: Sending 404 response when using callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Sorry for the poor title but I couldn't think of anything better. First look at the following code snippet:

```
app.use(function(request, response){
    request.addListener('end', function() {
        parseUrl(request.url, function(urlInfo) {
            if (urlInfo.notFound)
                response.send(404);
            else if (urlInfo.extension == '.html') {
                response.render(
                    urlInfo.path, 
                    { 
                        file: urlInfo.filenameWithoutExtension, 
                        url: urlInfo.url, 
                        directory: urlInfo.directory
                    },
                    function(error, html) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log("Error rendering view: " + error);
                            response.send(404);
                        }

                        response.send(html);
                    });
            }
            else
                file.serve(request, response);
        });
    }).resume();
});
```

This code does execute fine and serve pages. For certain requests parseUrl will make a call to a web service. The result of this service determines whether we should send a 404 response to the client or not. So when the service needs to be called the callback is invoked after the web request, otherwise the callback is just invoked inline.

The code executes fine but I get a 200 response. Looking at the log files it appears that the response.send(404) is called after the 200 response is sent. So I am assuming that the request.resume() is being called while the web request is taking place. This does make sense.

However whatever I do I can't get this to function how I want. I have tried:

- Moving the request.resume to the end of the callback
- Removing app.use and doing a request.resume at the end of the callback.

Generally whatever I do I break the server and it either times out or errors.

I have scoured the web and I am at a loss. If anybody is able to point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated. I am obviously missing a vital piece of knowledge here, I am new to node and express, this is my first project.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Mark

UPDATE:
Looking at this again and reading https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/doc/api/stream.markdown. It seems I need to explicitly call pause in the end event when using an asynchronous callback otherwise the stream will close as we return. I will try this later today and report back.

Comment: try to say `return` after this line `response.send(404);`.

Comment: Although I didn't think this would work I did just give it a go and it didn't make any difference. Thanks for your quick response though.

Comment: Just I thought this `response.send(html);` line will be called every time even there is a error. So I thought...

Comment: Mritunjay: Yes indeed it would, that is a bug, just not the bug I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simply a matter of pausing the request stream while the asynchronous call took place. In the end my method ended up like so:

```
app.use(function(request, response){
    request.on('end', function() {
        var parseStatus = parseUrl(request.url, function(urlInfo, status) {
            if (urlInfo.notFound)
                response.send(404);
            else if (urlInfo.extension == '.html') {
                response.render(
                    urlInfo.path,
                    {
                        file: urlInfo.filenameWithoutExtension,
                        url: urlInfo.url,
                        directory: urlInfo.directory
                    },
                    function(error, html) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log("Error rendering view: " + error);
                            response.send(404);
                        }
                        else
                            response.send(html);
                    });
            } else
                file.serve(request, response);

            if (status.executedAsynchronously)
                request.resume();
        });

        if (parseStatus.executedAsynchronously)
            request.pause();

    }).resume();
});
```

Comment: Remember to set the response statusCode = 404

Comment: Why? As per the documentation on expressjs.org any number passed to res.send() will be interpreted as the status code.